# Why do I get int value after typecasting but decimal value is in bracket?

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

I'm very familiar with c++ but today I notice something,

```
float a=(float)5/2; //this gives 2.5, its okay
float b=(float)(5/2); //this gives 2, why?
```

Please can you name this topic and any answer will help me.

Comment: The second line is doing integer division and then casting the result of that to `float`.

Answer (score 2):

In this expression in parentheses `(5/2)` there is used the integer arithmetic. The result of the expression is `2`.

In this expression `(float)5/2` there is used the floating arithmetic because one of the operands has the type `float` after its explicit casting `(float)5`.. The unary casting operator has a higher priority than the division operator `/`.

You could write equivalently

```
5.f/2
```

Comment: You mean (float)5/2, will make float 5 divided by  integer 2?

Comment: @KapilChauhan You are write. The casting is applied to the operand 5.

Comment: @ElonMuskOnStackoverflow Actually, the integer 2 is also (implicitly) converted to `float` and only then a (floating-point) division is performed.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with operator precedence. When you write

```
(float)5/2
```

it’s interpreted as

```
((float) 5) / 2
```

which means “treat 5 as a float, then divide it by the integer 2.” Therefore, the division is done as floating-point division.

When you write

```
(float)(5/2)
```

you’re saying “divide the integer 5 by the integer 2, then treat that as a float.” The division done is therefore integer division, which rounds down, so you get 2 as your result.